# Putting a link after document.getElementById('').innerHTML =

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a countdown timer and after it is done, I want it to show
"Completed, click here to continue."
Click here should be a hyperlink. But I don't know how to do this.
The Javascript timer:

```
var seconds = initialTime;
function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + "minutes " + remainingSeconds+ "seconds";
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed"; //Link should be shown after completed here
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
```

Also this is the html code where the live countdown and Completed+hyperlink should be shown:

```
<p class="p-2" style="font-family:R;">You can visit the site again in <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` means just that: Inner *HTML*. If you know how to create a link using HTML, just assign that HTML.

`document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Completed, <a href="https://your-link-goes-here/">click here</a> to continue';`

As a side note: I'm constantly seeing people here on Stack Overflow using `innerHTML` as the default and only way to add content to an element, even when they're just putting plain text into an element.

There's a another property, `innerText`, that's much better suited for that, and you don't have to worry that text will accidentally be treated as HTML or HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **insertAdjacentText()** function
I believe you need it right after your countdown then the 'beforeend' would do.

Example:

```
  document.getElementById("countdown").insertAdjacentHTML("beforerend", "<p>My new paragraph</p>");
```

Here is the full documentation on the aforementioned function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText

Comment: `innerHTML`, as the OP was using, is just fine. No need for `insertAdjacentHTML`. All they have to do is add the link to the HTML they're inserting.